# Ajax to prevent writing other than the words I specify

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are words that I have determined. How can I prevent the user from typing words other than those I have specified? in the textarea

example :

$cv= array("job","personel","human","hello",
"system","hobby","my life");

I set words in this way, if the user writes something other than these words, the screen should give an error.

Comment: If you only want to allow values from a predetermined set, is there a reason you aren't using [the `<select> element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)?

Comment: why have you tagged this question `javascript` and the only code seems to be a single line of `PHP`?

Comment: Because it should give the error instantaneously, for example, if there are no words in the textarea user specified, it should give an instant error. I can't do this in PHP. I know how to do it for php, but js codes are needed for instant error.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `keyUp` listener and parse the value of the textarea - use `.split[' ']` to get and array with the words and show the error if one of them is not found in your original array using `indexOf()`